# Why doesn't load data into my collection? mongodb

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, ejs

This is what appears on my mongo database:

[image]

This is my app.post to insert the data, when I Submit it console.log the object with the dates but with create It just says "null" ->

```
App listening on port 4000
{ '”title”': 'adaw', '”body”': 'dwdw' }
null { _id: new ObjectId("6274a7a58d8946ca10ae57c4"), __v: 0 }
```

```
app.post('/posts/store',(req,res)=>{
            console.log(req.body)
            BlogPost.create(req.body,(error,blogpost) =>{
                console.log(error,blogpost)
            res.redirect('/')
            })
            })`
```

Answer (score 0):

use `insertOne` instead of `create` for inserting in the database

here is the official doc [site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb)